# Get word in each loop using loop variable

Tags: awk, variable

I am trying to get the word in each loop. I can't figure out how to insert `i` into `print $2`.

```
while [ $i -lt 4 ] 
do
    A=$(awk -F_ '{print $2}' <<< 'one_two_test_three')
    echo $A
done
```

This will output, obviously:

```
two
two
two
two
```

What I want:

```
one
two
test
three
```

I tried:

```
A=$(awk -F_ '{print $($i)}' <<< 'one_two_test_three')
```

didn't work.

Comment: why you are insisting to use a for-loop where it doesn't necessary when you use `awk`. although I see you got the best answers to that too

Comment: I want to do something with the output. Not only printing it. I need to feed it to another command.

Comment: then what is the problem with using `tr '_' '\n' <<<'one_two_test_three' ]| to_another _command`?

Comment: another command is quite long. i prefer it on another line for readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way is to pass `bash/shell` variable into `awk` script as an argument via `-v` (`variable`) option:

```
i=1;
while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do
    A=$(awk -v i="$i" -F_ '{ print $i }' <<< 'one_two_test_three')
    echo $A
    ((i++))
done
```

The output:

```
one
two
test
three
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a shell loop to parse the data:

```
$ awk -F '_' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print $i }' <<<'one_two_test_three'
one
two
test
three
```

The script parses the input as a `_`-delimited list and prints each field.

Shorter:

```
$ awk -F '_' 'BEGIN { OFS="\n" } { $1=$1 } 1' <<< 'one_two_test_three'
one
two
test
three
```

This sets the output field separator to a newline, then it forces a re-forming of the whole record (with the new separator inserted) before printing the record.

Shorter:

```
$ tr '_' '\n' <<<'one_two_test_three'
one
two
test
three
```

Accessing the data in a loop:

```
tr '_' '\n' <<<'one_two_test_three' |
while read -r word; do
    printf 'Got "%s"\n' "$word"
done
```

This way, you don't call the utility that you use for parsing the data more than once.

Comment: Nice but I need the loop to be outside of awk.

Comment: @GeneCode Why? Are you planning to call `awk` for each line in a file? That's bound to be _extremely_ slow, especially if you're working on large data.

Comment: Data is not large. It is for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values do not have newlines, then:
Your code with minimum changes to get it working:
The shebang must be `#!/bin/bash` (ksh or zsh) since you are using `<<<`.

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 4 ] 
do
    A=$(awk -v var="$i" -F_ '{print $var}' <<< 'one_two_test_three')
    echo "$A"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

However, as the string comes from the shell, this could be simplified to:

```
IFS=_ read v1 v2 v3 v4 <<<'one_two_test_three'
printf '%s\n' "$v1" "$v2" "$v3" "$v4"
```

And using an array of values (variable number of values):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=_ read -a v <<<'one_two_test_three'
printf '%s\n' "${v[@]}"
```

If it is required that a simpler shell should be used:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=_ read v1 v2 v3 v4  <<-_expandvar_
one_two_test_three
_expandvar_
printf '%s\n' "$v1" "$v2" "$v3" "$v4"
```

Of course, if there is no need to set a variable nor it is a problem to set the value of IFS in an script:

```
#/bin/sh
a='one_two_test_three'
IFS=_
set -f
printf '%s\n' $a
```

Note that the variable is being used un-quoted, which may be insecure.